# Azure application gateway is failing to renew a ceritificate saying it is too large

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I'm trying to renew a HTTPS certificate in the Listener of an Application gateway, but after uploading it this message appears:

> Failed to save configuration changes to application gateway 'APPLICATION GATEWAY'.  Error: Application Gateway serialized Authentication Certificates size 131892 bytes is greater than the allowed 131072 bytes. Please try removing unused Authentication Certificates or reduce size of the certificates. Refer https://aka.ms/appgwremoveauthcert

I already tried following the procedures suggested for removing unused expired certificates, I removed all of the old certificates for this server, but it didn't work

I have already renewed this certificate many times, and just now this error started to appear. I tried to compare the size of the .pfx certificate with its predecessors and the size is the same, someone already received this message?

Answer (score 0):

Error with Application Gateway renew certificate usually occurs if the certificate already exists in Application Gateway auth cert list and matching it.

The best option is to submit a support request to Microsoft Azure Support

Answer (score 0):

There was an Hard-coded limit in Appgateway..So you need to go with V2 version only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).